# Siddhi 5, compare value before

Tags: siddhi

I need that when I get a temperature higher than the maximum temperature stored or lower than the minimum stored, I send an alert with the new temperature to the alert stream.

The problem that as I get a higher or lower temperature, first adds it to the maximum and / or minimum and then makes the check, so I never skip the alert.

How can I do so that I first compare the new temperature that comes to me and jump on alert?

```
@App:name("MaxTenMinutesApp")
define stream CargoStream (temperature int);

@sink(type='log', prefix='ouput >')
define stream OutputStream(temperature int, temperatureMax int, temperatureMin int);

@sink(type='log', prefix='alert >')
define stream AlertStream(temperature int);

@info(name='Alert')
from OutputStream[temperatureMax < temperature or temperatureMin > temperature ]
select temperature
insert into AlertStream;

@info(name='MaxTenMinutes')
from CargoStream#window.time(5 min)
select temperature, max(temperature) as temperatureMax, min(temperature) as temperatureMin
insert into OutputStream;
```

// LOGS

```
[2020-02-26_10-41-49_404] INFO {org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - ouput > : Event{timestamp=1582710109402, data=[10, 10, 10], isExpired=false} (Encoded)
[2020-02-26_10-41-54_600] INFO {org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - ouput > : Event{timestamp=1582710114596, data=[11, 11, 10], isExpired=false} (Encoded)
[2020-02-26_10-41-59_462] INFO {org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.output.sink.LogSink} - ouput > : Event{timestamp=1582710119461, data=[9, 11, 9], isExpired=false} (Encoded)
```

// EXAMPLE

```
VALUE   TEM MAX MIN  EVENT
5         5   5   5  SENT ALARM NEW MAX Y MIN
10       10  10   5  SENT ALARM NEW MAX
6         6  10   5  NOTHING
3         3  10   3  SENT ALARM NEW MIN
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the requirement. Using an example scenario.

Comment: At the beginning of the question is the purpose, I don't know what else I can explain.
I need to keep the maximum and minimum temperature. When a temperature greater than the maximum or less than the minimum arrives, I have to send that temperature to my alarm stream. The problem is that now I first set the temperature as maximum or minimum and then make the comparison and I need to do it the other way around. First check the new temperature if it is higher than the maximum or less than the minimum, if so send the alert and then set it as maximum or minimum if applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to maintain a placeholder with the last max and min temperatures and use it when input temperature comes in.

Please refer the sample code

```
@App:name("MaxTenMinutesApp")

define stream CargoStream (temperature int);

define table tempValueHolder (index int, temperatureMax int, temperatureMin int);

-- Sets initial value
define trigger triggerAtStart at 'start';

@sink(type='log', prefix='ouput >')
define stream OutputStream(temperature int, temperatureMax int, temperatureMin int);

@sink(type='log', prefix='alert >')
define stream AlertStream(temperature int);

@info(name='Sets initial value')
from triggerAtStart
select 0 as index, 0 as temperatureMax, 0 as temperatureMin
insert into tempValueHolder;

@info(name='Alert')
from CargoStream as strm
join tempValueHolder as tbl
select strm.temperature, tbl.temperatureMax, tbl.temperatureMin
insert into OutputStream;

from OutputStream[temperatureMax < temperature or temperatureMin > temperature ]
select temperature
insert into AlertStream;


@info(name='MaxTenMinutes')
from OutputStream#window.time(5 min)
select max(temperature) as temperatureMax, min(temperature) as temperatureMin
update tempValueHolder
on tempValueHolder.index == 0;
```